# Is it possible to find where a temporary email address is pointing/forwarding to?

Tags: email, spam-prevention

If I have a temporary email address that hides a real address, would it be possible for someone to find out the real address?

One possible way I can think of could be tracking a read receipt by sending over a pixel by pixel image and tracking the email address that loads it.

Are there any other ways or would this be pretty good at hiding the address from spammers?

Comment: _“and tracking the email address that loads it”_ – it would not be ”loaded by an email address”, but by the browser or mail client used to view it. And that should not send any data that allows to identify which email account is currently being viewed. (If it did, I would consider it to be broken.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you usually can't identify the "real address" behind a temporary one, unless the recipient replies to your message using its real email address (whether it's a manual response, or an automatic one like a read receipt).

That's especially true when your temporary email address is provided by a [disposable email provider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disposable_email_address). However, if your temporary address is indeed an alias on the same email server as the real address, the [SMTP VRFY](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-3.5.1) command may be used to resolve an alias to its real email address. But that SMTP feature is disabled on most email server, for obvious security reasons.

As CBroe pointed out, including an image or a link in your email wouldn't help you finding the real email address. Because mail content would be HTML, displayed by the brower, and not at all related to the email context. At most, it would tell you that the email was received and its content scanned. That's not even a guarantee that a human opened it, since some antispam filters resolve URLs to ensure they're not a threat.